# Perl Secure way to do Authentication like WHM

Tags: perl, authentication

I planning to implement a web system authentication and the maint part I want to focus is Security.
I have been reading a little about OAuth, OpenId, SAML, JWT, WS-Trust, etc.

My example is cpanel whm: 
demo.cpanel.net:2083

When you login you get a token security like this:

https://demo.cpanel.net:2083/cpsess4554629598

I see several modules in cpan and also I see modules relation to this case fromn cpanel:
forums.cpanel.net/threads/cpanel-rpms.557131/

Crypt::
SOAP::

My question is,  how can I Implement a system authentication like cpanel, witch modules should choose from cpan?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It depends on what application you have. If you are using a modern web framework, there are probably several plugins to do auth for each of them.